# Hawtio Camel 2.8.0-fuse-07-16 no trace messages

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

HawtIO shows the trace tab for my camel context, and when I run trace it shows messages counting up on the diagram. However, I never see any messages in the message table at the bottom. I'm using Camel 2.8.0-fuse-07-16. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a newer version of Camel to support tracing from hawtio. I think you would need the Camel version from JBoss Fuse 6.0 or better.